# How to change locale in NextJS using router?

Tags: next.js, locale

I'm trying to change locale in Next.js. Here's my component:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const ChooseLocale = () => {
    var router = useRouter();
    
    const changeLocale = (locale) => {
        router.push(router.pathname, router.pathname, { locale });
    }

    return <ul>
         <li onClick={() => changeLocale('en')}>En</li>
         <li onClick={() => changeLocale('fr')}>Fr</li>
         <li onClick={() => changeLocale('ru')}>Ru</li>
         ...
    </ul>
}
```

However, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')

And I get it on this line:

```
components/Navbar.js (24:15) @ changeLocale

  22 | 
  23 |     const changeLocale = (locale) => {
> 24 |         router.push(router.path, router.path, { locale });
     |               ^
  25 |     }
  26 | 
  27 |     return (
```

How can I change locale?

Comment: If you console.log router there it says undefined? What happens if you do a router?.push(router.path, router.path, { locale });

Comment: For one, you should use `router.asPath` instead of `router.pathname` (see [`router` object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object)). Also, the error mentions `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')` but the stack trace points to `router.push`, are you sure that's the error message you're seeing?